# Run node app with SSL on 443 port (on 80 is working)

Tags: apache-httpd, amazon-ec2, https, node.js, letsencrypt

I am trying to configure a server running on Amazon EC2.

I figured out how to run my node app on port 80, but now I'm trying to run on port 443, with Letsencrypt SSL. Before to work on port 80 I added:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

and

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

and everything worked fine. But now after installing Letsencrypt, I try to do the same thing, but with port 443, instead of 80 and it's not working.

Letsencrypt configured automatically for me all files so now redirect from http to https is working fine. On https:// I see ubuntu default website. App is working only with http:/...:3000

I've added 443 port to Security Groups on EC2.

What I can do?

Comment: Do you redirect HTTP and HTTPS to the same port?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to have certificate files on server, you need a service which will listen a port (e.g. 443) and respond using encrypting algorithms if the client expect to have ssl connection.  It can be done:

- on different ports, e.g. apache and nginx in such cate listen both 80 and 443, one for http and another for https.
- on the same port, e.g. mail server may use TLS as well on plain text protocol on the same port.

So, it depends on your service.